# computer not recognize my ubuntu on usb stick

Tags: live-usb, 15.10

Im experiencing weird situation and will be glad if any1 can help me out here
Im using lili to install linux live usb. I downloaded ubuntu from the official site and used lili to install it on usb and then everything went fine but didnt save my changes after I estart my computer and that is because when I installed it using lili the lili told me that the linux version is not in the compitability list. So then I downloaded linuxmint and again was working but as well didnt sav changes cuz it wasnt in the list. for sure that I changed my BIOS settings to read OS first fro usb. So it was problematic with the dont save changes thing but what wa ok is that the computer indead detected the usb. So then I used lili again but then tried to downloaded linux vversion straigh from the lili softwae and then it was in the compitabilt list and it told me that this version is fine. I did that with ubuntu, kubuntu, lubutu, and many others like mint and so but everytim since I install on the usb version from the compitability list the computer do not detct it and just runs windows.
Any1 know what the problem may B and how o fix it?
Thanks in advance and sry for my oor english, english is no nt my forst language

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Lili use Universal USB Installer

[Download Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) and open it up.

Select your Distribution.
then select an iso 
[image]
This is telling you that you are going to lose all data on your USB.
[image]

when its done you should see a window like this. 
[image]

Reboot and go into you're bios boot selection menu and boot from the USB. 
[image]

When you select a option on the USB boot menu i found that it took some time to boot into Ubuntu so it may take some time.